# Promise dosen't always fetch all values from web service

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

I am using promises to populate an array using multiple web services i created (`this.batGradesProvider.getAllCourseIds()` && `provider.getCoursesGrades`) **but i dont always get ALL the values from my web service. For example, for one of my test cases i KNOW I have an array of 6 course grades but i only receive 2 at the end**. Am i doing something wrong with my promise or perhaps with the forEach? Thanks in advance.

```
const promise = this.batGradesProvider.getAllCourseIds();

    promise.then((courseIds) => {

        courseIds.forEach((courseId) => {

            const promise2 = provider.getCoursesGrades(siteId, courseId, userid);
            promise2.then((data) => {

                for (let i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
                    // Get this course
                    const activity = data.data[i];

                    const activityObj: Activity = {
                        courseName: activity.courseName,
                        courseId: courseId,
                        name: activity.name,
                        status: activity.status,
                        complete: activity.complete,
                        score: activity.grade,
                        hasPassed: activity.hasPassed,
                        user: activity.username,
                        email: activity.useremail,
                        activityName: activity.activityname,
                        activityId: activity.activityid
                    };
                    // Add course to our running data
                    this.batGradesTable.push(activityObj);
                }

                return this.batGradesTable;
            });
        });
    })
```

Comment: You're trying to overwrite a constant. Use `var` or `let`.

Comment: Where? I declare Promise but never reassign it, i use promise && promise2

Comment: In your `data.data.length` loop.

Comment: it depends where are you trying to  access you grades. you should wait all promises to resolve.. I recommend you using Promise.all

Comment: will give that a shot, thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to perform a promise within a `forEach`, but the forEach function doesn't know that it should wait for the promise to complete.  You may want to get familiar with `Promise.all` when you want to perform many promises.

Try something like this:

```
this.batGradesProvider.getAllCourseIds().then((courseIds) => {
  return Promise.all(courseIds.map((courseId) => {
    return provider.getCoursesGrades(siteId, courseId, userid);
  }).then((results) => {
    this.batGradesTable = [];

    results.forEach((data) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
        const activity = data.data[i];
        const activityObj = { /* ... */ };
        this.batGradesTable.push(activityObject);
      }
    });

    return this.batGradesTable;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i looked at the documentation for Promise.all and implemented it, it worked perfectly along with my tests. Thanks so much